# How to upload an image to server local dir by ajax php, where html form haven't any traditional submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**HTML form codes** (localhost/oem/foo.html)

```
<form id="formUpload">
  <input id="photo" type="file"/>
</form>`
<div onclick='formSubmit()'>
  Upload Photo Now
</div>
```

**JS/JQuery codes** (inpage script)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#formUpload').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({ url:'/oem/response.php',
      type: 'POST', data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false, cache:false, processData: false,
    success: function(data){
      alert("Upload Successfully");
     }
    });
   });
  });

  function formSubmit(){
    $('formUpload').submit();`
  }
</script>
```

**PHP codes** (localhost/oem/response.php)

```
$sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "oem/images/".&_FILE['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath
);
```

But it will not work as I wish, it shows me a blank page after redirection.

**my question**: what is the main problem and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix classic form submit with ajax!
You have two options:

1. Use classic form submit and use $("form").submit() like you did.
2. Use ajax with FormData. If you need to change the page after ajax
   complete you can use window.location.href.

**EXAMPLE:**

1) Classic submit

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("form").submit(); // This will upload all fields and images in <input type='file'/>
});
```

2) Ajax

```
FormData formData= new FormData();
data.append("image", $("#image-input").prop("files")[0]);

$.ajax({..., data: formData, ...});
```

Comment: okey but after `$("form").submit();` raised event, ajax function will not worked properly

Comment: Like i said you CAN'T use form submit and ajax! Or one or another!
1) $("button").click(function() { $("#form").submit(); }); OR:
2) $("button").click(function() { $.ajax({...}); });

Comment: thank you bro but still confused, can you check my whole codes, is all correct ?

Comment: No, your code is wrong. All you need is the ajax part and call the $.ajax when you need it (you said that your form don't have a classic submit button)